# Export user data with django in django-admin to CSV

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-admin

I need to export to csv users of my database, so I have this more or less clear (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/), but what I need is to select which fields are exported previously.

Is it possible, using the model, show that you can select which fields will be exported?

Comment: Do you need to do this regularly or as a one-off?

Comment: if, on a regular basis.

The idea is to export the data of all users of the database to a csv file but specifying which fields have to copy the.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution to your question is to create an action in your user admin. Here is how to do it: go to your admin.py and do this

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponse
import csv, datetime

User = get_user_model()

def export_to_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;' 'filename={}.csv'.format(opts.verbose_name)
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    fields = [field for field in opts.get_fields() if not field.many_to_many and not field.one_to_many]
    # Write a first row with header information
    writer.writerow([field.verbose_name for field in fields])
    # Write data rows
    for obj in queryset:
        data_row = []
        for field in fields:
            value = getattr(obj, field.name)
            if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
                value = value.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            data_row.append(value)
        writer.writerow(data_row)

    return response

export_to_csv.short_description = 'Export to CSV'  #short description

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    '''
    Registers the action in your model admin
    '''
    actions = [export_to_csv]
```

With this you will be able to select the specific users that you want to export their data and export it at once.

Comment: Excellent answer! Just a minor correction, on response['Content-Disposition'] there's a missing '=' char, it should be: 'filename={}.csv'

Answer (score 3):

From the console, you could simply try

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as csv:
...     for user in User.objects.all():
...         d = '%s, %s, %s,\n' % (user.username, user.last_name, user.first_name)
...         csv.write(d)
```

where set `d` to be whichever fields you want to save.

Of course, this will be a pain if you want to do this several times - it's probably a much better idea to create a [custom admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, in the end I've had to do this, since all data is always exported and then the columns that do not want to be removed with excell.

Answer (score 2):

From Django 3.2 onwards, you also have to register `export_as_csv` as an "action" by adding a decorator. See this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) for the official documentation.